# siunitx align numrange

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx

I have a table in which I use `\numrange` of the `siunitx` package.
 I would like to center align that column at the range-phrase. If I align it left, it sort of works, but if I align it center, it is not good enough. How can I solve this?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx} 


\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{All measured and their estimated outcome variables during 30 minutes of chair exercises}
\label{table:outcomes}
\sisetup{
range-phrase = --
}

\begin{tabular}{
                l
                c
                c
                c
                %S[parse-numbers = false,input-decimal-markers={-},output-decimal-marker = \text{--}]
                S[table-format=3.1, table-text-alignment=center]
                }

\multicolumn{1}{l}{}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{SD}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Median}&
\multicolumn{1}{c}{Range}\
\hline


\%vo2max (mL/min) & 66.0 & 16.5 & 66.9 & \numrange{30.3}{115.8}\\



&&& 54.6 & \numrange{30.3}{77.7}\\


&&& 69.9 & \numrange{43.8}{115.8} \


\hline




\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I will provide a working example immediately..

Comment: @Duikboot What's `mymemoir`?

Comment: It's a modified memoir documentclass. I'll adjust it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following isn't a direct solution to the problem you're trying to solve. Instead, I suggest you consider pursuing a different solution. Why? Personally, I think that if one tries to present an entire range of numbers in a single column, too much numerical information is being crammed into a confined space. In order to give your readers a chance to really parse and absorb the data you're presenting, it's probably preferable for you to list the minima and maxima in separate columns -- joined, of course, by an overall header that says "Range". The following MWE illustrates what I'm trying to express.

The MWE also uses the `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\cmidrule`, and `\bottomrule` macros of the `booktabs` package to generate well-spaced "rules" (horizontal lines) of varying thickness. These make a table immediately much more professional-looking, compared to what's achievable with `\hline` and `\cline` (the basic LaTeX rule-drawing commands).

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs} 
% booktabs package for well-spaced horizontal rules

\begin{document} 
\begin{table}
\caption{All measured and their estimated outcome variables during 30 minutes of chair exercises}
\label{table:outcomes}

\medskip\centering
\sisetup{table-format=2.1}
\begin{tabular}{l SSSS S[table-format=3.1]}
\toprule
& {Mean}&{SD} & {Median}& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Range}\\
\cmidrule{5-6}
& & & & {Lower} & {Upper}\\
\midrule
\%vo2max (mL/min) & 66.0 & 16.5 & 66.9 & 30.3 & 115.8\\
&&& 54.6 & 30.3 &  77.7\\
&&& 69.9 & 43.8 & 115.8 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I concur. While `\numrange` can be handy in text, tables are a different matter; maybe one can use it in a column with numerical data, in case no precise value can be reported for the specific case. If *all* entries are a range, then it's better to split into two columns.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392828/align-items-by-the-range-phrase-in-a-s-colum-type-from-siunitx-package) and I tryed a lot of ways, so there is the way how I solve it:

**1.** Split the last column in 3 different columns

**2.** The last 3 columns must be in the format `S`, `c` and `S`

**3.** Reduce the gap between the columns to `1ex`

**4.** In the last 3 columns write your ranges: the lower value in one column, your `range-phrase` in other column and the upper value in the last column

Your MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{All measured and their estimated outcome variables during 30 minutes of chair exercises}
\label{table:outcomes}
\sisetup{
range-phrase = --
}
\begin{tabular}{%
l
c
c
c
S[table-format=3.1, table-text-alignment=center]    %<-- Columns splited
@{\hspace{1ex}}                                     %<-- Column separation
c                                                   %<-- Columns splited
@{\hspace{1ex}}                                     %<-- Column separation
S[table-format=3.1, table-text-alignment=center]    %<-- Columns splited
}
& Mean & SD & Median & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Range}\\ %I just used multicolumn for the splited columns
\hline
\%vo2max \si{\mL/\minute} & 66.0 & 16.5 & 66.9 & 30.3 & -- & 115.8 \\ %<- I use the \si option for the units
                          &      &      & 54.6 & 30.3 & -- & 77.7  \\ %<- Ranges splited and separated by your own range-phrase
                          &      &      & 69.9 & 43.8 & -- & 115.8 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Note that if the table heading is wider than the range contents, the code doesn't work correctly