# Align items by the range-phrase in a S colum type from siunitx package

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx, s-column-type

I'm creating a table with a `S` column type from the `siunitx` package. The items in this column are a range of numbers. There is a way to align this items, in the second column by the `range-phrase` "to"?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabular}{SS}
\toprule
\textbf{Head 1 (\si{\cm})}          &
\textbf{Head 2 (\si{\mm})}          \\ 
\midrule
30,12 & \numrange{2,4}{4,84} \\ 
3,45 & \numrange{356}{445} \\
300,42 & \numrange{0,487}{1,334} \\
33,00 & \numrange{6}{21} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Trying a lot, I answered this question in another user question. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392854/107689) is the answer