# How to vertically align and format numbers in scientific notation inside tables?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, punctuation, decimal-number, scientific-notation

I need to get a centered alignment inside the first column with respect to the dash "-" and insiedthe last column. Can you also show how to customize and visualize only two decimal places in the scientific notation?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1,group-digits=false]}
\newcommand\mytab[1]{\textbf{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{test}
\label{tab:manifold:database:factor:k:CIs}
\begin{tabular}{@{} c T{2.2} S @{}}
\toprule
\textbf{No. of PLOs ranges} & \textbf{Factor k} & \textbf{Radius of CI (km)} \\ \midrule
1-5 & 2.0 & 1.858e6 \\
6-15 & 2.5 & 2.323e6 \\
16-25 & 3.0 & 2.788e6 \\
26-40 & 3.5 & 3.252e6 \\
41-50 & 4.0 & 3.717e6 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/392854/133968

Comment: If everything is x10^6, just put that in the header and omit from the cells. Also to reduce space between No. of, use No.\ of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[siunitx](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) will centre the first column if you use a custom decimal marker `-`. As to the last column, you need to set `round-mode` and `round-precision` and format numbers to display exponents as well

Just one note, `output-decimal-marker` also accepts formatting macros. Therefore, you could use something like `\textrm{\,--\,}` and have slightly more control over how to display range markers (see the second screenshot)

[image]

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=top,skip=3pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{test}
\label{tab:manifold:database:factor:k:CIs}
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  S[table-format=2.2,input-decimal-markers=-,output-decimal-marker=-]
  S[table-format=1.1]
  S[table-format=1.2e1,round-mode=figures,round-precision=3]
@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{No. of PLOs ranges} & \textbf{Factor k} & \textbf{Radius of CI (km)} \\ \midrule
1-5 & 2.0 & 1.858e6 \\
6-15 & 2.5 & 2.323e6 \\
16-25 & 3.0 & 2.788e6 \\
26-40 & 3.5 & 3.252e6 \\
41-50 & 4.0 & 3.717e6 \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```